# Core data fetch unsuccessful from parent NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using parent/child `NSManagedObjectContext` structure to do some core data operations in a separate thread. The operations and their codes are in the following order:

**1) Delete all the entries from the core data (Using parent/child structure)**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObjectContext *bgContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
bgContext.parentContext = context;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[bgContext performBlockAndWait:^{

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [bgContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
        [bgContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        [bgContext save:nil];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ object deleted",entityDescription);

}];

[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    [context save:nil];
}];
```

**2) Insert New entries to core data (Using parent/child structure)**

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectContext *bgContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    bgContext.parentContext = context;

    [bgContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        for (int i = 0; i<quantityCol.count; i++)
        {
            NSManagedObject *Sales = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transactions" inManagedObjectContext:bgContext];

            NSString *product = [productTitleCol objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *city = [cityTitleCol objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *customer = [customerTitleCol objectAtIndex:i];

            [Sales setValue:product forKey:@"product"];
            [Sales setValue:city forKey:@"city"];
            [Sales setValue:customer forKey:@"customer"];

            NSError *err;
            [bgContext save:&err];
            if (err) {
                NSLog(@"%@",err);
            }
            [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                [self.managedObjectContext  save:nil];
            }];
        }
    }];
```

3) Fetch Items (Using the NSManagedObjectContext on main thread)

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Transactions"];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transactions" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Date" ascending:NO]];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
distinctDate = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

The order of everything is as above. Now everything seems to work fine and the main thread is not blocked at any time up to the third step. When i try to fetch items from core data i get nothing. Note that its my first time using the child/parent structure so i am not sure if i got the whole thing right.

Comment: You are fetching a `Date` property, but your code to insert new values does not set that property?

Comment: This is just dummy code, ive already handled that. The problem is something else.

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to get data  after saving core data?

Comment: just do a try by commenting     "fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;"